# Software Center won't start: "AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'FontSelectionDialog' "

Tags: upgrade, software-center, python

When I try to run software-center from the terminal it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 33, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 76, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 224, in _load
    overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 523, in <module>
    class FontSelectionDialog(Gtk.FontSelectionDialog, Dialog):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'FontSelectionDialog'
```

A similar response is given when upgrade-manager or the advanced-settings (for Gnome Shell settings) is attempted. These are all the malfunctioning applications I know of right now, but there may be more. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and the Gnome-Shell environment. The error occurred after an automatic upgrade (I think). I have found people with the same or similar problem but none of the fixes has worked for me. I have tried reinstalling python2.7 and some of the other packages via Synaptic. I can still upgrade my distribution since I can run Ubuntu Tweak, but I'd like to sort this out. I have been using some of the experimental repositories for Gnome Shell development but since I figured this might be the reason for the error I purged (successfully I hope) and disabled them via Ubuntu Tweak.

Help on a basic knowledge level would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does ``apt-cache policy python-gobject`` print?

Comment: It prints: 

Installed: 3.0.2-1~oneiric1
  Candidate: 3.0.2-1~oneiric1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.2-1~oneiric1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.0-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages
     3.0.0-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main i386 Packages

Comment: Alrigthy, so what to do? Surely there must be some  way to resolve the problem and proceed with non-developmental upgrades again?

Comment: Issue Resolved! I thank you all. Adding back ppa:ricotz/testing and then purging it with ppa-purge solved the problem for me. My Gnome Shell usage will go through the stable channels from now on, at least until I know more about it. Again, thanks.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this [one](http://askubuntu.com/q/75539/5014). However, the older question didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 4):

Install the package *ppa-purge* activate the PPAs again and use `ppa-purge` to deactivate them.

If that doesn't work use the "Origin" button in Synaptic to see the list of used package sources. For every package in every non-official package source use Package-> Force Version from the menu and select the most recent version from an official source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`

`sudo apt-get update`